# Using PHP SoapClient with Java JAX-WS RI (Webservice)

Tags: java, php, soap, web-services, jax-ws

For a new project, we want to build a web service in Java using JAX-WS RI, and for the web service client, we want to use PHP.

In a small tutorial about JAX-WS RI I found this example web service:

```
package webservice;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public class Calculator {
    public long addValues(int val1, int val2) {
        return val1 + val2;
    }
}
```

and for the web server:

```
package webservice;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import webservice.Calculator;

public class CalculatorServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Calculator server = new Calculator();
        Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/calculator", server);
    }
}
```

Starting the Server and browsing the WDSL with the URL "http://localhost:8080/calculator?wsdl" works perfectly. But calling the web service from PHP fails.

My very simple PHP call looks like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8080/calculator?wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
echo 'Sum: '.$client->addValues(4, 5);
```

But then I either get a "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded..." or an "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost:8080/calculator?wsdl' ..." exception.

I have tested the PHP SoapClient() with other web services and they work without any issues. Is there a known issue with JAX-WS RI in combination with PHP, or is there an error in my web service I didn't see?

I have found [this bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48216), but even updating to PHP 5.3.2 didn't solve the problem.

Can anyone tell me what to do? And by the way, my Java version running on Windows 7 x64 is the following:

```
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it times out it looks like php isn't able to resolve the WSDL URL properly. Have you tried a file_get_contents()/curl on the WSDL Url? Maybe try calling the IP instead of localhost and see how that goes.

Comment: That's really crazy. A file_get_contents(), with "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" times out. A curl with both succeeds. And a SoapClient() with "localhost" times out, but with "127.0.0.1" succeeds.

I don't understand where the problem might be (maybe it is something in my XAMPP Apache config or in the hosts file) but now I know how to get it working.

Thanks a lot!!!